# App Crashing After Adding Applovin Max Banner Ad

Tags: java, android, mobile-ad-mediation, applovin

I have tried implementing the banner ad code following the correct documentation as seen [here](https://dash.applovin.com/documentation/mediation/android/ad-formats/banners). Now when I run the app both on my Virtual Device and Mobile phone  crashes after showing the splash screen.

My error is pointing to:

```
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

I have also implemented MaxAdViewAdListener in my MainActivity.java

On my activity_main design below is how I have added the banner ad code as below:

```
        <com.applovin.mediation.ads.MaxAdView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/banner_height"
            android:background="@color/banner_background_color"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            maxads:adUnitId="e96696c22#####" />
```

The Ad although displays in the Design section on Android studio. Below are the exceptions displayed in the Run section:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.packagename.eaxample/com.packagename.eaxample.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #371 in com.packagename.eaxample:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #371 in com.packagename.eaxample:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class com.applovin.mediation.ads.MaxAdView

 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #371 in com.packagename.example:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #371 in com.packagename.example/activity_main: Error inflating class com.applovin.mediation.ads.MaxAdView
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #371 in com.packagename.example:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class com.applovin.mediation.ads.MaxAdView
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this `Error inflating class com.applovin.mediation.ads.MaxAdView`, you have to check the following:

1. Check if your `com.applovin.mediation.ads.MaxAdView` in XML file can be referenced. If not, you may have to confirm if you have imported the correct libraries.
2. It uses an additional namespace: `maxads:adUnitId`. Check if the corresponding link for this namespace is correctly set: `xmlns:maxads="http://schemas.applovin.com/android/1.0"`

Comment: This did it, I just updated the  xmlns:maxads="http://schemas.applovin.com/android/1.0" in my layout file thanks @Enowneb